# remove delete button on first set of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/NzbRQ/2/

I allow the user to add multiple rows of fields, but I do not want to include a delete link on the very first row of fields, so they can't delete all the fields.

Also, how do I limit it to only 3 rows of fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzbRQ/7/)

For the first part of hiding the delete on the first row, I called the following on page load:

```
$(".removeoutcome").hide();
```

Then to make sure they can't add more than 3 or delete the last one, I've added length checks in your `click` methods, see:

```
$('.addoutcome').live('click', function() {
    if ($(".outcomegroup").length < 3) {
        $('#template').clone().removeAttr('id').insertAfter($(this).closest('.outcomegroup')).find('.minus').show();
        renumber();
    }
});

$('.removeoutcome').live('click', function() {
    if ($(".outcomegroup").length > 1) {
        $(this).closest('.outcomegroup').remove();
        renumber()
    }
});
```

Also, on a side note, `live` is deprecated now, so if you're using jQuery 1.7, change these methods to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or if you're pre-1.7, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Answer (score 3):

You can just hide the del for first element and limit it to add only 3 more set using the following code

```
var count = 3;
$('.minus').first().hide();
$('.addoutcome').live('click', function() {
 count--;
   if(count < 0 )return;  
    $('#template').clone().removeAttr('id').insertAfter($(this).closest('.outcomegroup')).find('.minus').show();

});
```

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/uW9NQ/

Comment: Your fiddle needs to account for removal of rows.

Comment: @jwatts Isn't my one removing rows when del is clicked?, it is removing for me. :s

Comment: What I meant was that the row counter does not count back up when a row is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/NzbRQ/5/

First off, ditch `.live`.  I added the `section` to give a more specific selector than `body`, but there's probably something better that you can use in your original DOM.

Just don't remove the last row with some simple logic.  Your logic for showing the future "del" link was actually already there!  You don't even really need the last-row-removal logic at all since just not displaying "del" is enough, but I was just being thorough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why anyone haven't paid close attention to this line:

```
.find('.minus').show();
```

where he definitely was un-hiding the `del` element. In short, the only thing you need to do is add the proper CSS rule:

```
.minus { display: none; }
```

and that's it, the first element won't show a `del` link and the others will.

The limit to three elements simply.

```
$("[parent element]").on('click', '.addoutcome', function() {
  if($('.addoutcome').length > 2) return;    
  ...
});
```

A better selector `[parent selector]` is needed and depends totally in your layout. Basically, it is the element that wraps all these elements, the parent element of all of them.

Comment: Upvote for hiding the initial `.minus` via css.  Downvote for still suggestiong `.live`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, There you go. Actually, I didn't care too much about it.